# Java: opencv & openni

Tags: java, opencv, openni

I was wondering if anyone has been able to use **openni** in combination with **opencv** in **java**?
For example that you get the depth stream in a IplImage etc ... I'm currently trying to do this , but i'm not sure where to start.

If anyone who has done this want to share their knowledge or some code i would be grateful.

My code so far:

/

```
*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.


/**
 *
 * @author olivierjanssens
 */

package kitouch;

import com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader;
import com.googlecode.javacv.*;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_calib3d.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.*;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import org.OpenNI.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class KiTouch {

    private Context context;
    private final String SAMPLE_XML_FILE = "/Users/olivierjanssens/Development/Kinect/OpenNI/Samples/Config/SamplesConfig.xml";    
    private OutArg<ScriptNode> scriptNode;
    private DepthGenerator depthGen;
    private BufferedImage bimg;
     int width, height;
    IplImage depthImage;
    private float histogram[];
     private byte[] imgbytes;
    CanvasFrame frame = new CanvasFrame("Some Title");

    public KiTouch() {
        try {
            scriptNode = new OutArg<ScriptNode>();
            context = Context.createFromXmlFile(SAMPLE_XML_FILE, scriptNode);

            depthGen = DepthGenerator.create(context);
            DepthMetaData depthMD = depthGen.getMetaData();

            histogram = new float[10000];
            width = depthMD.getFullXRes();
            height = depthMD.getFullYRes();

            imgbytes = new byte[width*height];

            DataBufferByte dataBuffer = new DataBufferByte(imgbytes, width*height);
            Raster raster = Raster.createPackedRaster(dataBuffer, width, height, 8, null);
            bimg = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
            bimg.setData(raster);
            depthImage = IplImage.create(width, height, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

        } catch (GeneralException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }


    }


    private void calcHist(DepthMetaData depthMD)
    {
        // reset
        for (int i = 0; i < histogram.length; ++i)
            histogram[i] = 0;

        ShortBuffer depth = depthMD.getData().createShortBuffer();
        depth.rewind();

        int points = 0;
        while(depth.remaining() > 0)
        {
            short depthVal = depth.get();
            if (depthVal != 0)
            {
                histogram[depthVal]++;
                points++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < histogram.length; i++)
        {
            histogram[i] += histogram[i-1];
        }

        if (points > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < histogram.length; i++)
            {
                histogram[i] = (int)(256 * (1.0f - (histogram[i] / (float)points)));
            }
        }
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }

     void updateDepth()
    {
        try {
            DepthMetaData depthMD = depthGen.getMetaData();

            context.waitAnyUpdateAll();

            calcHist(depthMD);
            ShortBuffer depth = depthMD.getData().createShortBuffer();
            depth.rewind();

            while(depth.remaining() > 0)
            {
                int pos = depth.position();
                short pixel = depth.get();
                imgbytes[pos] = (byte)histogram[pixel];
            }
            depthImage.createFrom(bimg);
            frame.showImage(depthImage);

        } catch (GeneralException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

and to call this code :

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package kitouch;

import org.OpenNI.GeneralException;

/**
 *
 * @author olivierjanssens
 */
public class kiTouchApp {
     public static void main(String s[]) throws GeneralException {
         KiTouch kit = new KiTouch();


          while(true) {
            kit.updateDepth();
        }
    }
}
```

Though i'm getting a black frame. So it doens't work yet

When i do not initalize the IplImage like i do here but just IplImage depthImage = new IplImage(); i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:613)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage(opencv_core.java:1005)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage(opencv_core.java:931)
at com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame.showImage(CanvasFrame.java:331)
at kitouch.KiTouch.paint(KiTouch.java:138)
at kitouch.kiTouchApp.main(kiTouchApp.java:21)
```

Thx in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did play with OpenNI and Java, but using [Processing](http://processing.org/) and the available wrappers([SimpleOpenNI](http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/) and [OpenCV](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/)) which for my modest needs at the moment work well.
Here's a very basic example:

```
import hypermedia.video.*;
import SimpleOpenNI.*;

SimpleOpenNI  ni;
OpenCV cv;
PImage user;
void setup()
{
  ni = new SimpleOpenNI(this);
  ni.enableScene();
  background(200,0,0);
  strokeWeight(4);
  size(ni.sceneWidth() , ni.sceneHeight()); 
  cv = new OpenCV( this );
  cv.allocate(width,height);
}
void draw()
{
  //OpenNI
  ni.update();
  user = ni.sceneImage(); 
  //OpenCV
  cv.copy(user);
  cv.blur( OpenCV.BLUR, 17 );
  Blob[] blobs = cv.blobs( width,height, OpenCV.MAX_VERTICES, true, OpenCV.MAX_VERTICES*4 );

  //diplay
  image(cv.image(),0,0);
  //*
  fill(255);
  for(Blob b : blobs){
    beginShape();
      for(java.awt.Point p : b.points) vertex(p.x,p.y);
    endShape(CLOSE);
  }
  //*/
}
```

Note that this OpenCV wrapper uses OpenCV 1.0 and also you might want to use your own Java classes, rather using the Processing library. In this case try the [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) wrapper.
Regarding the depth stream, if you look in the `org.OpenNI.Samples.SimpleViewer` class that comes with OpenNI, you will notice that the depth bytes from OpenNI are written to a BufferedImage, which I imagine can be integrated with OpenCV,etc.

```
 public SimpleViewer() {

        try {
            scriptNode = new OutArg<ScriptNode>();
            context = Context.createFromXmlFile(SAMPLE_XML_FILE, scriptNode);

            depthGen = DepthGenerator.create(context);
            DepthMetaData depthMD = depthGen.getMetaData();

            histogram = new float[10000];
            width = depthMD.getFullXRes();
            height = depthMD.getFullYRes();

            imgbytes = new byte[width*height];

            DataBufferByte dataBuffer = new DataBufferByte(imgbytes, width*height);
            Raster raster = Raster.createPackedRaster(dataBuffer, width, height, 8, null);
            bimg = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
            bimg.setData(raster);

        } catch (GeneralException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Currently i'm looking into the BufferedImage, i believe that a BufferedImage can be converted to an IplImage. Oh and btw i'm using the javacv

Comment: Sure, googling for **java iplimage** should get you [interesting results](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2009/05/14/combining-javas-bufferedimage-and-opencvs-iplimage/).

Comment: true, but there is a built in conversion i tried : 'depthImage.createFrom(bimg);

frame.showImage(depthImage);'

Which i do in the updatedepth function. But i get a nullpointer though. So have to keep searching

Comment: I've added my code to the question, maybe you can have a look at it ? (I'm not getting a null pointer atm only a black screen)

Comment: Unfortunately can't test right now on the computer I'm on, but could you check if you can display bimg (or a BufferedImage from bimg) on the screen) ? If that works, the problem is either with depthImage.createFrom(), either with the byte array somehow not getting across, but first, make sure bimg isn't null/empty in the first place. HTH

Comment: Aye, i checked this and the bimg is not empty, i can display it and see the depth. So the problem must be the 'depthImage.createFrom()'.

Comment: Hmm...hard to tell why the IplImage won't initialize from the depth byte array (maybe channels don't match, not sure :s). I googled a bit more and found the [OpenKinectFrameGrabber](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/trunk/javacv/src/com/googlecode/javacv/OpenKinectFrameGrabber.java?spec=svn102&r=102) class in the javacv project. I haven't tried it, but I suppose it wouldn't be in the main trunk if it didn't. I noticed that uses libfreenect instead of OpenNI though. Still, if it's just the depth you're after(no gestures/skeleton), OpenKinectFrameGrabber should be useful.

Comment: noticed you initialize the IplImage with IPL_DEPTH_8U, while they use IPL_DEPTH_16U (grayscale values in the depth map are from 0 to 2048 AFAIK). Probably you want to look at public IplImage grabDepth() method in the class OpenKinectFrameGrabber class. Maybe it can be adapted for your existing OpenNI code, if the supplied freenect version isn't useful. HTH

Comment: well i need the skeleton model and gestures so libfreenect is not an option.

Comment: It seems the IplImage is not empty , because when i extract the BufferedImage and display that ... i can see it.

Comment: I see. I hope you can grab what you need from OpenKinectFrameGrabber's  grabDepth() method. I see there's a some byte array shuffling there as well: `if (iplDepth > 8 && ByteOrder.nativeOrder().equals(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)) {
            ByteBuffer  bb  = rawDepthImage.getByteBuffer();
            ShortBuffer in  = bb.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN   ).asShortBuffer();
            ShortBuffer out = bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer();
            out.put(in);
        }` Try to adapt that method to your code.

Comment: Ok I'll look at this code later, currently i can work by converting the bufferimage to IplImage and back to a bufferimage. If i have some time left later on i'll look into that one.

Comment: I found the answer, instead of displaying the stream using frame.showImage(test), i used cvShowImage("test",test). And it works perfectly. Thank you for your help

Comment: Glad to help, and thanks for sharing your finds ! Good luck with your project!